# MVVM data Binding validation

Tags: java, android, xml, validation, binding

I want to validate Sign up User data with MVVM and data Binding. Here is my code,  guide me please :

**Activity**:

```
    registerViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(RegisterViewModel.class);
    binding.setSignUpObject(new RegisterRequest());
    binding.setSignUpClickListener(registerViewModel);
```

**Model**:

```
public class RegisterRequest extends BaseObservable {


@SerializedName("Email")
private String userEmail;
@SerializedName("Password")
private String userPassword;
@Expose
private String userConfirmPassword;
@SerializedName("Phone")
private String userPhone;
@SerializedName("ImagePath")
private String imagePath;
@SerializedName("Name")
private String userName;

@Expose
private RegisterErrors registerErrors;
}
```

// of course with setters with nonotifyPropertyChanged and getters with @Bindable annotation
// and I create a  RegisterErrors class to use it with error on app:error xml

**RegisterErrors** :

```
public class RegisterErrors {

private String userEmailError;
private String userPasswordError;
private String userConfirmPasswordError;
private String userPhoneError;
private String imagePathError;
private String userNameError;
```

}

**XML**:

```
   <variable
        name="signUpObject"
        type="com.rabe7.community.model.request.register.RegisterRequest" />

    <variable
        name="signUpClickListener"
        type="com.rabe7.community.view_model.user_management.RegisterViewModel" />

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlackTransparent">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/et_sign_up_user_name"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp16w"
                                android:hint="@string/label_sign_up_user_name"
                                app:error="@{signUpObject.registerErrors.userNameError}"
                                android:inputType="text"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:text="@={signUpObject.userName}"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

                        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

the question is .. I want to validate the user input after a click on submit button .. how can I validate it on view model with binding

I try this :

**viewModel**:

```
    public void onRegisterSubmitClicked(RegisterRequest registerRequest){
    this.registerRequest = registerRequest;

    if(registerRequest.getUserName().length()<6){
        registerRequest.getRegisterErrors().setUserNameError("error");
        }

}
```

But `app:error` does not work and I don't know what to do .. so help me, please :)

Comment: is "app:error" a @bindingadapter? Can you post it?

Comment: no 
some article say that it's built in on android xml or data binding so i don't know .. you have another solution ?

Comment: Well I have two things to say: I highly recommend that you migrate to viewbinding if possible (way easier). The other thing: I have a project running data binding and I cant find this "app: error", I asume it is a custom databindingadapter like those https://github.com/chenriquevz/challenge-alpha/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/challenge_alpha/ui/home/BindingAdapters.kt
https://github.com/chenriquevz/challenge-alpha/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_home.xml

Comment: " I highly recommend that you migrate to viewbinding if possible (way easier)." 
i can't understand ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this in your ViewModel:

```
 /**
     * Two way bind-able fields
     */
    var userName: String = ""
```

Also, write a method that validates your screen in ViewModel

```
fun validateSignupScreen() {
    if (userName.isEmpty()) {
        return
    } else if (userPassword.isEmpty()) {
        return
    } else {
        // Do your work here 
    }
}
```

And in Your Activity class do this:

```
registerViewModel.validateSignupScreen()
```

Comment: i want to da all logic in view model with Data binding so 
1- user input the data 
2- signUpObject hold the data 
3- user click submit 
4- object delivered to view model 
5- validate the object 
the missing part is update ui from view model